# How can install SVN on bluehost using putty

Tags: svn, bluehost

I have need to install subversion using bluehost ssh account.
 i am trying to follow bellow steps

cd ~
mkdir src
mkdir ~/apache-libexeccdir
cd src
wget http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/apr/apr-util-1.3.10.tar.gz
wget http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/apr/apr-1.4.2.tar.gz

But i am getting error 
--2014-01-21 21:06:48--  http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/apr/apr-util-1.2.12.tar.gz
Resolving www.gtlib.gatech.edu... 128.61.111.11, 128.61.111.9, 128.61.111.10, ...
Connecting to www.gtlib.gatech.edu|128.61.111.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-01-21 21:06:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.

is there any other way to get install subversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to download an old version of APR and APR-util from a public mirror.  That's not likely to work since usually the public mirrors only have the most recent versions of the software.

You can find older versions of the Apache Software Foundation's archive site:
http://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/